# How to read only Integers from txt file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using (BinaryReader reader = 
    new BinaryReader(File.Open(@"Assets\saves\one.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    year = reader.ReadInt32();
    month = reader.ReadInt32();
}
```

I want to get first 2 int values from txt file, the first value is 2018 and the second is 4, but instead of this values both year and month are 577005860.

Comment: You're using a `BinaryReader` on a .txt file? My guess is the "integers" you're trying to read are actually text.

Comment: How are your ints separated in the text file? By line?

Comment: They are separated by space

Answer (score 1):

You are using `BinaryReader`, which is attempting to extract the numbers as if they are stored in a flat binary file. Read it as a text file instead. You should use a `StreamReader`, and then use `Int32.parse` to convert the number to an `Int32`.